# How to measure the ephemeral space used by every container

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I know how to measure needed RAM and CPU usage, but not how to measure used disk space of every container in a k8s cluster.

I've tried cAdvisor, but only provides stats per node, not per container.

https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/198

Any recommended tool/procedure?
In this way I could specify in the `resources` section of a pod, sensible values.

Comment: Have you gone through this [doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/storage/understanding-ephemeral-storage.html#storage-ephemeral-storage-monitoring_understanding-ephemeral-storage) /bin/df as a tool to monitor ephemeral storage usage on the volume where ephemeral container data is located. Can you have a try with this. for more information Refer to this [blog](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/kubernetes-ephemeral-storage) by Sudip Sengupta.

Comment: `df` provides info about used space in a node, but I don't know to which containers it belongs.

Comment: I have posted as an answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

df command you need to run in the container and also go through this [doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/storage/understanding-ephemeral-storage.html#storage-ephemeral-storage-monitoring_understanding-ephemeral-storage), /bin/df as a tool to monitor ephemeral storage usage on the volume where ephemeral container data is located. Refer to this [blog](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/kubernetes-ephemeral-storage) by Sudip Sengupta for more information.

**Try the below commands to know kubernetes container's ephemeral-storage usage details:**

- Try **du -sh / [run inside a container]** : du -sh will give the space
  consumed by your container files. Which simply returns the amount of
  disk space the current directory and all those stuff in it are using
  as a whole, something like: 2.4G.
- Can you run   `kubectl exec <podname> -c <container_name>  –df -h` in  each container you will get the used space in that particular   container.
- Refer to this [ephemeral storage-consumption Management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-emphemeralstorage-consumption)

**Below is the Output** :  [image: output]

Also you can check the complete file size using the `du -h someDir command`.

- Refer to this [blog](https://blog.px.dev/container-filesystems/#title)  by Omid Azizi for inspecting the container file systems.
- Seems to be you are going to specify in the resources section of a
  pod refer to this [Setting requests and limits for local ephemeral
  storage.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#setting-requests-and-limits-for-local-ephemeral-storage)

Comment: `df` must be run as `root` user, otherwise many warnings are shown like `du: can't open '/run/sudo': Permission denied`